# Limit Growl to one app only

Tags: applications, growl

Is it possible to limit Growl notifications to one App only? I'm really bothered by notifications by Adium, Bowtie and lots more but I don't want to deactivate each of them manually.

Something like a whitelist for Growl-enabled apps would come in quite handy here. Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Very simple: Go to System Preferences --> (other) Growl --> then choose the applications tab. From here you can choose which apps you want to give growl notifications.

Comment: This is the right answer?  I have to repeat it every reboot?

Comment: You shouldn't have to repeat it. It works/sticks for me. What issue are you having exactly?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to let everything alert you, but by default make the alerts invisible. For the one or two apps you want, customize them to be visible.

To make alerts invisible, under **Display Options** you could set it to default to SMS and give a bogus number, or find some other technique.